# How can I get keyword arguments in sqlalchemy.FunctionElement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a function which would produce statement equivalent to `datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=5, minutes=4)`. I want to be able to call it like `utc_after(days=5, minutes=4)`.

It should be similar to [`utcnow()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.current_timestamp), as described in [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.current_timestamp).

Here is an example what I got working so far (one dialect only for brevity):

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import FunctionElement
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.types import DateTime

class utc_after(FunctionElement):
    type = DateTime()
    name = 'utc_after'

@compiles(utc_after, 'sqlite')
def sqlite_utc_after(element, compiler, **kwargs):
    days, hours = list(element.clauses)
    return "datetime('now', '+%s day', '+%s hours')" % (days.value, hours.value)
```

It works. I can use it as in:

```
week_after_submission = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=utc_after(7, 0))
```

Obviously this is only a stub of the final code (it needs +/- formatting, minutes, seconds and so on).

The **question** is: how can I use keyword arguments from FunctionElement so I could have:

```
next_week = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=utc_after(days=7))
```

When I specify `utc_after(days=7)`, `element.clauses` is empty.
So far I tried using `kwargs` from `sqlite_utc_after` (these are empty), digging through `element` properties, and searching clues in documentation, without results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the keyword argument as a property.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import GenericFunction
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, String, MetaData

class last_value(GenericFunction):

    def __init__(self, *clauses, ignore_nulls=False, **kwargs):
        self.ignore_nulls = ignore_nulls
        super().__init__(*clauses, **kwargs)


@compiles(last_value)
def visit_last_value(element, compiler, **kwargs):
    clauses = element.clauses
    ignore_nulls = element.ignore_nulls
    ignore_nulls_clause = ' ignore nulls' if ignore_nulls else ''
    return 'last_value(%s%s)' % (compiler.process(clauses), ignore_nulls_clause)


def test_last_value():
    m = MetaData()
    t = Table('test', m, Column('a', String), Column('b', String))
    c = func.last_value(t.c.a, ignore_nulls=True)
    s = select([c])
    assert ' '.join(str(s).split()) == 'SELECT last_value(test.a ignore nulls) AS last_value_1 FROM test'
```